# Three js animate shape

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using Three.js, if I create a mesh by drawing a shape and extruding, how can I animate the underlying shape to alter the resulting mesh?

A simple example:

```
drawShape: function(){
    var shape = new THREE.Shape();
    shape.moveTo(0, 0);
    shape.arc(0,0,30,0,(Math.PI*1.9),true);
    return shape;
},

var shapeGeom = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(this.drawShape(), options);
```

I would like to alter the geometry by changing the shape path/arc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used morph targets to achieve this.  I made a function to create the frames in advance and then animated through them. Using the above function to draw, something like this:

```
createMorphTargets: function(geom,initVal,targetVal){
    var numFrames = 60;
    var fraqStep = (1/numFrames);
    var diff = targetVal-initVal;
    var stepVal = (targetVal-initVal)/numFrames;
    for(var i=1;i<60;i++){
        var delta = TWEEN.Easing.Quintic.InOut(fraqStep*i);
        var lerpVal = initVal+(diff*(delta));
        var mesh = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(this.drawShape(lerpVal), this.bevelOptions);

        geom.morphTargets.push({
            name:'target-'+i,vertices:mesh.vertices
        });
    }
},
```